# Add formated current timestamp inside a html src

Tags: html, timestamp, src

I'm new to the HTML.
I need the src = "http://IpAddress/Name_02-10-2020_08_50_00.jpg" in the slide show html.
Is there any idea to get this result?

Here's what I typed, but it is not working.

```
<div class="slideshow-container">
  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <img src="http://IpAddress/name_"+ getMonth(Date.now())+"-"+getDate(Date.now())+"-"+
         getFullYear(Date.now())+"-"+getHours(Date.now())+"_"+ getMinutes(Date.now())+"_"+
         getSeconds(Date.now())+".jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>
```

Thank you.

Comment: <div class="slideshow-container">

<div class="mySlides fade">
  <img src="http://IpAddress/name_"+ getMonth(Date.now())+"-"+getDate(Date.now())+"-"+
  getFullYear(Date.now())+"-"+getHours(Date.now())+"_"+ getMinutes(Date.now())+"_"+
  getSeconds(Date.now())+".jpg" style="width:100%">
</div>

Answer (score 0):

I think it will be a good practice to use one date object, so may be create one function to return whole string. For example,

```
function getValue() {
    const date = new Date();
    const src =
        `http://IpAddress/name_${date.getMonth()}-${date.getDate()}-${date.getFullYear()}-${date.getHours()}_${date.getMinutes()}_${date.getSeconds()}.jpg`;
    return src;
}
```